# Pattern matching symbols to have alpha inputs

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to strip the symbols from my Strings and this isn't working. It's like Pattern Matcher seems broke. I know I'm just missing something. Thanks.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,\\.;:{}/\\[\\]<>?`~!@#$%^&*()_+=]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("April's");
Matcher m1 = p.matcher("Place to go!");
setName(m.replaceAll(""));
setDescription(m1.replaceAll(""));
```

I'm expected to see this:

Input- "Sarah's Scope"

Output- "Sarahs Scope"

What I'm currently seeing is:

Input- "Sarah's Scope"

Output- "Sarah's Scope"

Comment: What are you seeing?  What do you expect to see?

Comment: @Taylor I edited my question. It's like the array counter is off for Pattern Matcher and that's it's matching one character off because of an index calculation.

Comment: You're not escaping characters, so . will match any character, you want \\.  Also you've got s in there, so any punctuation or the letter s?  Suggest you read up on regex in java.

Comment: I know that I need to escape characters it's just knowing which ones in Java that need to be double escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern instead:

```
"[\\'\\\",\\.;:{}/\\[\\]<>\\?`~!@#\\$%\\^&\\*\\(\\)_\\+=]"
```

or thi:

```
"[\\'\\\",\\.;:{}/\\[\\]<>\\?\\`~!@#\\$%\\^&\\*\\(\\)_\\+=]"
```

But maybe it would be easier to do with:

```
"[^[a-z][A-Z][0-9]]"
```

or

```
"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

since you are searching any symbol it would be any character except letters and numbers.

Comment: This doesn't compile because of your escape sequence for the quote is wrong.

Comment: @AprilRandolph try doing `\\\"` instead of the `\\"`

Comment: I feel like you copied my idea, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. You can simplify your regex further: `"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"`

Comment: @Quincunx - Ups! Sorry. I hadn't seen it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to strip all characters that aren't letters or whitespace. If that is the case, then this will work:

```
"[^\\sA-Za-z]"
```

Or, if you want to include numbers:

```
"[^\\sA-Za-z0-9]"
```

Or, if you know specifically what you want to keep: `"[^` followed by what you want to keep, then followed by `]"`.

---

If you are just trying to remove all characters of a `String` that don't match the pattern, then it is easier to use `String.replaceAll()`.

---

For more on regex, see [regex tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `\\p{Punct}` regex property here to weed out all punctuation characters:

Consider this code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Sarah's Scope");
System.out.println(m.replaceAll(""));
//> Sarahs Scope
```